# Changing button position in WordPress/WooCommerce shop

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am building a web shop and have installed a new plugin and it has moved my "Add to cart" button. I am using the latest version of WordPress along with the latest version of WooCommerce to run my site.

[Here the page in question](http://www.ceehydrosystems.com/new/products/)

So the PHP outputs:
`

```
<a href="http://www.ceehydrosystems.com/new/product/cee-echo/">
    <img width="300" height="300" src="http://www.ceehydrosystems.com/new/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/ceeecho-2-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="ceeecho-2">      
    <span class="price"><br></span>
</a>

<p class="product-enquiry-button-custom">
    <a href="http://www.ceehydrosystems.com/new/product/cee-echo/"></a>
    <a data-title="CEE ECHO™" data-id="2081" class="product-enquiry-click click-link-btn product-btn-2081" href="">Add to Quote</a>
</p>

<div class="bg-shop">
    <h4><a href="http://www.ceehydrosystems.com/new/product/cee-echo/">CEE ECHO™</a></h4>
    <div class="line_under"><div class="line_left"></div><div class="line_center"></div><div class="line_right"></div></div>
    <p>A compact dual frequency survey echo sounder – the perfect partner for your survey GPS</p>
    <div class="links"></div>
</div>
```

`

But I want to know if anyone knows of the file to change that outputs the HTML instead of positioning the button with CSS. Ideally I would like to rearrange the order of which the HTML is output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to prioritize the button from the shop loop item hook, Not sure if it will work but try the function below. Add this code to your theme's functions.php

```
function remove_loop_button(){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');

function add_loop_button(){
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 100 );
}
add_action('init','add_loop_button');
```